# Detailed UWB+BLE Connection Tutorial for Controlling BLE Device with UWB-enabled Android Phones

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, uwb

fellow developers!

I'm currently trying an exciting project that involves setting up a UWB (Ultra-Wideband) + BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) as OOB connection between two Pixel 7 Pro smartphones. One of the smartphones will act as the controller, and the other will be the controllee. The ultimate goal is to use this setup to control a BLE device.

Are there any tutorials or resources available that walk through the process of setting up UWB + BLE communication on Android devices?